# Java input from text file with an unusual format

Tags: java, graph, io

So I realize this text format may not be very unusual. However, I've been trying many ideas to read this correctly into the objects needed and know there has to be a better way. Here is what the file looks like:

```
S S n
B 1 E 2

B N n
C 2 F 3

C N n
D 2 GA 4

D N n
GA 1

E N n
B 1 F 3 H 6

F N n
I 3 GA 3 C 1

A N g

H B b
U 2 GB 2 F 1

I N n
GA 2 GB 2

GB N g
```

So the first line of each pair is the name of the node S, whether its a starting node N/s then whether its a goal node g/n
The second line is the children of node S, and their distance weight.
For example, Node S has child node B with a distance of 1, and child node E with a distance of 2

I'm working with two object types, Nodes, and Edges.
Example below. (Constructors ommitted)

Does anyone have tips on how to read this type of input efficiently?

```
public class Edge {
public String start;
public String end;
public int weight;


public class Node {

public String name;
public boolean start = false;
public boolean goal = false;
public ArrayList<Edge> adjecentNodes = new ArrayList<Edge>();
```

Comment: I did, sorry about that, I'm expanding it with successive edits

Comment: First approach: ask the people who gave you that file! And of course: reading the file efficiently **very much** depends on the objects you want to create. So *anything* we would need to help you is on information that only have; and that you are not sharing here. You know, we are not wizards here.

Comment: The real issue I'm having i suppose is dealing with the two separate objects I'm making and the space between each pair of information is throwing me off for my file input. I tried to include as much information as I could in the post, I just hadn't editted it all in yet

Comment: Some quick hints: an Edge ... does **not** need start/end positions (and if you want to keep them, they should be of type Node; not String!) ... and for "filling" that data ... if there is no reasonable answer later on, I will write down something.

Comment: Interesting, I would think you would at least need the end position in order to build out the graph later though correct? Or else I'm not grasping how you could tie the edge to be connected whichever nodes they are connecting, could you elaborate on that point?

Answer (score 1):

Actually your question is almost too broad and unspecific, but I am in the mood to give you some starting points. But please understand that you could easily fill several hours of computer science lectures on this topic; and that is not going to happen here.

First, you have to clarify some requirements (for yourself; or together with the folks working on this project):

1. Do you really need to focus on **efficient** reading/building of your graph? I rather doubt that: building the graph happens **once**; but the computations that you probably do later on may run for a much longer time. So one primary focus should be on designing that object/class model that allows you to **efficiently** solve the problems that you want to solve on that graph! For example: it might be beneficial to already *sort* edges by distance/weight when creating the graph. Or maybe not. Depends on later use cases! And even when you are talking about **huge** files that need efficient processing ... that still means: you are talking about **huge** graphs; so all the more reason to find a good **model** for that graph.
2. Your description of the file is not clear. For example: is this a (un)directed graph? Meaning - can you travel on any edge in *both* direction? And sorry, I didn't get what a "goal" node is supposed to be. (I guess you have *directed* edges that go one way only, as that would explain those rows in the example where nodes do not have any children). Of course, sometimes requirements become clear in that moment when you start writing real code. But this here is really about concepts/data/algorithms. So the earlier you answer all such questions, the better for you.

Secondly, a suggestion in which order to do things:

1. As said, clarify all your requirements. Spend some serious time just **thinking** about the properties of the graphs you are dealing with; and what problems you later have to solve on them.
2. Start coding; ideally you use TDD/unit testing here. Because all of the things you are going to do can be nicely sliced into small work packages, and each one could be tested with unit-tests. Do **not** write all your code first, to then, after 2 days running your first experiments! The first thing you code: your Node/Edge classes ... because you want to play around with things like: what arguments do my constructors need? how can I make my classes immutable (data is pushed in by constructors only)? Do I want distance to be a property of my Edge; or can I just go with **Node** objects (and represent edges as `Map<Node, Integer>` --- meaning each node just knows its neighbors and the distance to get there!)
3. Then, when you are **convinced** that that Node/Edge fit your problem, then you start writing code that takes **strings** and builds Node/Edges out of those strings.
4. You also went to spent some time on writing good *dump* methods; ideally you call graph.dump() ... and that produces a string matching your input format (makes a nice test later on: reading + dumping should result in identical files!)
5. Then, when "building from strings" works ... then you write the few lines of "file parsing code" that uses some BufferedReader, FileReader, Scanner, Whatever mechanism to dissect your input file into strings ... which you then feed into the methods you created above for step 3.

And, seriously: if this is for school/learning:

- Try to talk to your peers often. Have them look at what you are doing. Not too early, but also not too late.
- Really, seriously: consider throwing away stuff; and starting from scratch again. For each of the steps above, or after going through the whole sequence. It is an incredible experience to do that; because typically, you come up with new, different, interesting ideas each time you do that.

And finally, some specific hints:

It is tempting to use "public" (writable) fields like start/end/... in your classes. But: consider not doing that. Try to *hide* as much of the internals of your classes. Because that will make it easier (or *possible*!) later on to change one part of your program without the need to change anything else, too.

Example:

```
class Edge {
  private final int distance;
  private final Node target;

  public Edge(int distance, Node target) {
    this.distance = distance; this.target = target;
  }
  ...
```

This creates an **immutable** object - you can't change its core internal properties after the object was created. That is very often helpful.

Then: *override* methods like *toString()*, *equals()*, *hashCode()* in your classes; and use them. For example, toString() can be used to create a nice, human-readable dump of a node.

Finally: if you liked all of that, consider remembering my user id; and when you reach enough reputation to "upvote", come back and upvote ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I really appreciate it. I'm just trying to learn as best I can, and rethinking the approach sometimes is what I need. I do talk to peers often but it seems a lot of people either havent started this program or don't know how to do it yet.

Comment: Early submit mistake again-
Anyways, to answer some specifics as well, this is a directed graph, and I will be performing a depth first search traversal with cycle checking. I've found some good starting points to do the depth first search and I understand that part fairly well, but I've been really conflicted on how to set up the actual graph in code, I've seen examples with stacks as well as arraylists, and other methods. but I digress, thanks for the example of how you would do the edge class, and I have upvoted your post and appreciate it.